# Multiple buttons and 'a' tags that post from a single page

Tags: php, laravel

I have multiple buttons and a tags that are submitted from a single view. The 'a' tag submits using javascript. I want to use the same method, one form post, but I want to check which button or 'a' tag is set. I don't know how to do that?

```
if (isset($_POST['a_tag_name'])) {
    //data table 1
}elseif(isset($_POST['a_tag_name2'])){
    //different data from table 2
} //calling buttons
elseif (isset($_POST['en'])) {
    $language = 'en';
} elseif (isset($_POST['sq'])) {
    $language = 'sq';
} elseif (isset($_POST['tr'])) {
    $language = 'tr';
}
<a id="slider-content-link" onclick="javascript:getimageid('{{$row->id}}')" id="view_post">
    <h3 class="ml2">
        <p class="letters" align="right">{{$row->title}}</p>
    </h3>
</a>
```

Comment: let's show your js code

Answer (score 0):

Make your "buttons" be actually "submit buttons".

Only the submit button you click will be passed as parameter in the post. Then just check which of all the submit is passed, and there you have it.